# What is Secret in Cloud Run equivalent in gcloud command line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to use secret in Cloud Run for Anthos by gcloud command line
Is there any example about how to use this secret in any documents?
I'm already looking for it in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run
but nowhere in the doc talking about secret

[Secret in Cloud Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpYXI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secret mounts in "Cloud Run for Anthos" are regular Kubernetes Secrets. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/ You can use `kubectl create secret` command to create it.

You can browse the list of ConfigMaps and Secrets at the Cloud Console https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/config but you can't create them or edit them there. Currently, kubectl is the only option.

Comment: I was convinced that the Cloud Run (Knative) contract preventing any volume mount to the container. Here I understand that you can mount a secret volume? Is it because it's a virutal volume linked to a ConfigMap and not to a persistent disk?

Comment: Yes, please refer to the Knative API reference.